# type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to populate data retrieved from a web API :

```
  void asyncInitState() async {
    BulletinController bulletinController = BulletinController() ;
    var value = await bulletinController.AfficherEtablissement();
    value.forEach((entry) {
      print(entry['id']);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncInitState(); 
    super.initState();
  }
```

this is the "AfficherEtablissement()" method :

```
 Future<dynamic> AfficherEtablissement() async {
     final response =
     await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
       //decode
       print(parsedJson);
       Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
       return data  ;
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load');
     }
   }
```

i am getting this error :

```
type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'
```

int his line :

```
print(entry['id']);
```

Comment: It does not answer to your question but you don't need to call `super.initState();` two times. It has no sense, you are overriding `initState()` and you need to call base class only one time before writing you custom logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **AfficherEtablissement** function returns a **Map** object, so for iteration on response you should use:

```
value.forEach((key, value) {
   // do something
});
```

Note that the function you pass to forEach takes two parameters (key, value).

Answer (score 0):

The AfficherEtablissement function returns Map<String, dynamic>, so for iteration on response you should use:

```
 void asyncInitState() async {
    BulletinController bulletinController = BulletinController() ;
    Map<String, dynamic> value = await bulletinController.AfficherEtablissement();
    value.forEach((String key, dynamic entry) {
      print(entry['id']);
    });
  }
```